# How to tell if code snippet is imported or main when using exec()

Tags: python

First off, I'm familiar with the usual python import check boilerplate:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_stuff()
```

I have a small python gui that allows execution of other python scripts in another thread using exec(). Before the usual "Why would you even do that?" questions, the gui is used to manage some custom hardware and it uses scripts for automated testing that are written and executed from the gui. Lets just assume its all good reasoning for now.

Anyway, I ran into some issues with some scripts importing functions from another script but executing code in the import. The usual protection doesn't work properly (or perhaps too well) because `__name__` is never set to `"__main__"` when called from `exec()`. It seems to get set to the same value in both cases (running 'directly' and imported). I suspected it still counts as imported when run from `exec()`.

Is there another way to detect if the code is imported or not that would work through `exec()`? If its a bit messy or convoluted, I'll wrap it in a convenience function (e.g. `is_main()`) Will I have to start search from the stack with the inspect module?

Comment: How exactly is `exec` being used? `exec` itself doesn't differentiate, because it's neither executing a script nor importing a module: it's either executing a code object or parsing and compiling source code found in a `str` object.

Comment: A proper [mre] others could run to see the problem themselves would do this question a lot of good. Among other things, showing your code would make it easier to tell if there _is_ in fact any distinction between your question and the duplicate proposed.